# Google fonts: special characters (arrows) not showing in IE10

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-10, webfonts, google-webfonts, google-font-api

http://jsfiddle.net/Praak/

Try in different browsers, only IE will not apply "Source Sans Pro" font for ←→.
Removing `text` parameter fixes it, but I need only 2 arrows from this font and do not want to load all characters.
Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to encode special characters before using in URL.
Here is online tool for URL encoding [www.url-encode-decode.com](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) (don't forget to select correct encoding, utf-8 or another)

`←→` after url encoding: `%E2%86%90%E2%86%92`

and there's no need to specify the `subset=` parameter when using `text=`.

Here is final, cross-browser solution
http://jsfiddle.net/Praak/2/